# can i make the printer check the database if the user exist

Tags: python, sql, sockets, printing, request

i want when someone trying to use the printer and I want the printer to check if they exist in the database or no

Comment: There are printer, that do have an auth framework. If not so, you have to set up a print server in the middle, that does do the authentication

Comment: you can take a look at papercut

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what printer? What system? What database?

Comment: i have users and i want to limit the user access to the printer like each user have 15 pages  to print how can I do that